# How to embed one nib into another?

Tags: iphone, nib

There are many view that share a common part in my current project so I just visualize a way to encapsulate the common part into a nib file that could be shared by many controllers by embedding it to their corresponding nib file. Although I know how to do it programmatically, I still believe there should be a way to achieve this simply in Interface Builder. Are there anyone who has achieved this and would you like to point the way out?

Answer (score 0):

You can add in your NIB file a view called "Content", for example. In your code, the only thing you need to do is add your new UIViewController's view inside the "Content"'s view. This way, you can achieve a view that holds common data, while the only thing you do is to change the view inside the "Content"'s view.